# Android Webview exclude url from overrid method

Tags: android, android-webview

Hey guys i need help with my webview app
I have a webview that opens a url and i override it so that it only opens in my application not on the webbrowser but the problem i am having is i want open url from youtube.com in my android webbrowser. I tryed to do like this but did't work any help please.
I only want youtube links to be opend in webbrowser but other link should just be opend inside my app. now it opens all links in m app 
How do i open youtube links in browser?

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("www.youtube.com/")) {
        // magic
        return false;
    } else {
        v.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working properly ?

Comment: I want open links from youtube in Android default webbrowser not inside my app and the links are in the web not on the app if the links ware in the app i could just open them by intent

Answer (score 0):

This is something that worked for me:

```
    @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){          
        if ( (url.contains("vid:") || url.contains("http://youtube.com")) == true ){
        // Load new URL Don't override URL Link
        view.getContext().startActivity(
        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

        return true;
        }
        // Return true to override url loading (In this case do nothing).
        return false;
    }
```

So in your case this could be:

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
    if ( (url.contains("vid:") || url.contains("http://youtube.com")) == true ) {
         // Load new URL Don't override URL Link
     view.getContext().startActivity(
     new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));      
     return false;
     } else {
       v.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
     }
   }
```